# Редирект и куки в условиях "единой точки входа" и https

Tags: php, cookie, https, редирект

Проблема связанная с "единой точкой входа", "редиректом" и возможно еще с https. Как я понял эти элементы не очень дружат друг с другом.
Если коротко, то у меня есть главный файл index.php на который отправляются все URL (или URI, я не особо шарю) и дополнительные файлы, которые подгружаются в зависимости от URL (такие как input.php и profile.php). Когда человек входит под своим логином и паролем создаются куки. Так вот, если человек пытается зайти по ссылке site.net/profile то ему подгружается profile.php. Но если у него не сохранены куки с информацией входа, то его должно перекинуть на site.net/input где будет подгружен input.php.
Для этого я использую header ('Location:/input'). И логично использовать этот код именно в profile.php, но появляется ошибка "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...". Как я понял появляется она из-за того что в файле index.php уже есть некоторый код, например там задается фавикон, так как с концепцией "единой точки входа" это логично. В итоге приходится прописывать header ('Location:/input') в index.php с условием if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/profile') {if (!isset($_COOKIE['login'])){ header ('Location:/input') ;}} что конечно работает, но это неудобно учитывая что можно было бы просто написать if (!isset($_COOKIE['login'])){ header ('Location:/input') ;} в profile.php.
Я точно раньше юзал header ('Location:/input') прямо посреди кода и не выбивало никаких ошибок, но я его использовал без "единой точки входа" и возможно сайт тогда был на http.
Вопрос, если сайт будет на http то header ('Location:/input') можно писать где угодно? И если это так то тогда как удобно использовать редирект с условием что сайт с "единой точкой входа" и он на https?
Кстати с куками та же фигня что и с редиректом, их удобно прописывать в input.php с обработкой формы но нет, та же ошибка и тоже нужно выносить этот код и обработку формы до всего кода.

Comment: а все потому что не надо пхп код мешать с html. сначала делайте всю логику, а потом уже формируйте вывод.  на крайний случай используйте буферизацию вывода.

Comment: header ('Location:/input') требуется вызывать перед echo, а НЕ после или во время, т.к. сначала передаются заголовки, а потом уже контент. 
Если НЕ хотите заморачиваться, то используйте ob_start и ob_end_flush, который был дан в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае можете обойти проблему используя буфферизацию вывода в index.php:

```
<?php

// В самом начале файла
ob_start();

// Далее весь ваш код

// В самом конце файла
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Но как вам уже посоветовали, лучше отделить логику приложения от вывода. Почитайте на досуге о технике программирования **"Модель-Вид-Контроллер"**.